# GitHub Workflow - auto push to git repo after pull_request

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I host my git-repo on GitHub.com. Several developers contribute code to either the develop- or feature branch respectively. Once all the tests have passed, the changes are merged into master.

Now, once such a pull-request/merge has been done, the master brach shall be pushed automatically to another GitHub-Repo (where another team picks it up). This is when "Workflows" come into play.
So I created this yaml file to trigger a "git push" after a successfull pull-requrest:

```
name: push master to official repository
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  gitHubPush:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - run: "git push https://github.com/OFFICIAL/MyProject master"
```

But this doesn't work. I get:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> Error: Process completed with exit code 128.

The GitHub Account is registered as "Contributor" on OFFICIAL.

Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to checkout your repository first:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

More information about checkout options to find the best fitting your needs here: https://github.com/actions/checkout/

Comment: Unfortunately no. I still get: remote: Repository not found. But when you click on the Link it opens without problem.